# Type-checking "let"-bindings / function definitions efficiently in System F

Tags: types, ocaml

Consider the following (pseudo-)OCaml code:

```
let foo = <something> in
  begin
    foo a
    foo b
    foo c
    ...
    foo z
  end
```

(a-z being metavariables, nothing specific)

I read [Pierce, TAPL, Ch. 22.7] that in ML-style polymorphism, type checking can be done efficiently by calculating the principal type for "foo", generalizing (thereby introducing ML-style polymorphism) and checking against that type for every occurence of "foo" in the body (would be 26 times here).

Now my question is: what if we are in System F?  What if you can't verify the type of a function by a constraint typing algorithm?  Sure, typing rules for System F exist, but implementing them means that you would have to replace every occurence of "foo" with "<something>" and re-typecheck "<something>" every time you call "foo".

Comment: It seems to me that in System F, the type of `foo` would have to be provided by the programmer, and it would be this provided type that would be used to check `foo a`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System F is usually described in an explicitely typed style: functions
are annotated with the type of their argument (`λ(x:σ).t`), and type
abstractions (`Λα.t`) and applications (`t[σ]`) are present in the
syntax.

With this presentation, it is easy to compute the type of a term, in
your example `<something>`. This type is unique and in particular it is "the most general type": there is no confusion possible. `foo` will have this type. If it is an
arrow type `σ → τ`, then all parameters given to `foo` (`a`,`b`...)
will have to have type `σ`. If it is a polymorphic type
`Λα₁Λα₂...σ→τ`, then before using it as a function you must
instantiate the values of the variables `α₁`, `α₂` etc... You cannot
write `foo a` but should instead write `foo[τ₁][τ₂][..] a`.

This can provide you the same amount of polymorphism than in ML : in
ML, the abstractions are transparently added (generalization of let
bindings) and eliminated (instanciations at use sites). In explicit
System F, you do this by hand.

For example :

```
let id = Λα.λ(x:α).x in
(id [int] 1, id [string] "foo", id [∀α. α → α] id)
```

There are other presentations of System F with various degrees of
impliciteness, where the inference problem of regaining the explicit
types is not always decidable. You can see ML as a specific inference
process for implicit System F, which is not complete in the sense that
it will not accept all terms that would have been typable in System
F. For attempts at doing inference for full System F, see [this
summary](http://lists.seas.upenn.edu/pipermail/types-list/2004/000314.html)
(since the time of writing (2004), the work on Remy's MLF has
progressed, and led to the HML/HMF work by Leijen, and FPH by
Vytionitis et al.).